# Changing position of product fields

Tags: nodes

I'm learning Drupal Commerce with a Commerce Kickstart installation. I understood in part the way products are displayed, with variation types and content types.

Have made some changes like visible/hidden product fields, and change the order product fields are displayed. But didn't get how, for example, in

http://demo.commerceguys.com/ck/bags-cases/commerce-guys-laptop-bag

the bag image stay positioned left side and others product fields right side.

I'm running Drupal 7 and Commerce Kickstart 2

Edit: See that image go left side because the variation type field is *images*. I've created variation type with variation type field *image*. If set do that way, the image stay in the same column as the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `View Source` of the webpage in your browser you will see that the CSS says `class=" ... grid-N ... "` so part of the answer is that they are using a Grid based CSS framework to layout the node content.

This type of stuff is easily achieveable with [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group), [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) or [Fences](http://drupal.org/project/fences) to layout a content type in this fashion.

Comment: The Fences comes with Kickstart 2. Editing 
Home > Administration > Store settings > Product settings > Variation types > Bags & Cases > Manage fields > Images, in _Wrapper markup_ field, the option selected is _figure -- Figure with optional caption_. So I chose this option in my new variation type. In fact, I chose the same options for the others fields at all. Still, the image doesn't position left side.